# Cypher Query support

Tags: neo4j, cypher

[image: sample graph]

Hi,
For the above graph, need your help with the cypher query for the below scenario.

1) return all the nodes with relationship R1 connected to node R1. I want to get S1, S2 ,S3 as the output of the query

2) From the remaining nodes R2, R3 etc., if there is no direct relationship added, is there a way to query the bottom up node i.e. S1,S2 etc., from node R5

Appreciate your inputs

Comment: I'm new to neo4j,  below is what i tried..All the RNode and SNodes have the labels  . But don't get the right nodes                                                                                            MATCH (:RNode { name:'R1' })--(SNode)
RETURN (SNode)

Comment: In your example, SNode is a variable name. You need to have a label here if SNodes are distinct types from your other nodes, otherwise this will match on every node connected to R1. You may want to reread the Cypher dev manual or go through the tutorial in the browser app to get familiar with Cypher syntax.

Comment: This works, MATCH (:RNode { name:'R1' })
- [*]- (n:S1) return n

Comment: Good, do you need anything else then? Please update your description with what's working now, what you still need, and details on what you can rely on in the graph? For example, on question 2, is R1 a definite node on the path, or just some R node? And are the relationships to the SNodes always going to be labeled R1, or is this just an example of what might be there? In order to form a path, we need some state to rely on, whether that's the relationship types to follow, specific nodes to match on, the number of relationships to traverse, anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

Your graph is missing node labels (ie types), if all the nodes are of the same type and the names are R1...S5 then:
1)

```
MATCH (node:Node)-[:R1]->(x) where node.name ="R1"
RETURN x
```

this means find all nodes that are connected to a node with name R1 by the relationship R1

2) your question is not clear, are you trying to find all S-nodes given R5?
given R5

```
MATCH(node:Node)-[:*1-7]-(node-s:Node) where node.name="R5" AND node-s.name =~ "S.*"
RETURN (node-s)
```

the `[:*1-7]` means path of length 1 to 7

This would be easier, if your nodes had labels...